# How to filter R::findAll() result through a joined column? - RedBeanPHP4

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I am new to RedBeanPHP I studied their documentation but wasn't able to find how to filter a `R::findAll()` result like how we are filtering a shared list through `$bean->withCondition('...', [...]);`?

**My case:**

I have two tables `user, usertype` and they have a one-to-many relationship mean every user must have a usertype and multiple users can be the same type.

`table: usertype`

```
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(10)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| psname | varchar(10)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`table: user`

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| username    | varchar(16)         | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                |
| password    | char(60)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| email       | varchar(64)         | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                |
| is_active   | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| created_at  | datetime            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| usertype_id | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

So now I want to retrieve only the users whose type is not `ADMIN` but the following is not working:

`$not_admins = R::findAll('user', 'WHERE @joined.usertype.type != ?', ['ADMIN']);`

You can check that the same syntax works for `withCondition()` method but only for retrieving related records or by RedBeanPHP term works/filters only shared beans.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a sub-query on where, for ex:

`R::findAll('users', '(SELECT type FROM usertype WHERE usertype.id = users.id) != :type', [':type'=>'admin']);`

Another way, you can run a normal query as suggested by Nick, but use `$query = R::getAll('...')` instead of `$query = R::exec('...');` then you can use `R::convertToBeans($query);` to get beans object or access data via array (without convert)

Answer (score 0):

Easier to avoid rb joins and just do mysql

use

`R::exec('select from user inner join other on some id=id where foo = :foo',['foo'=>'some_value']`

Comment: didnt read your full table structure, i figured youd get the gist of it